# Can someone tell me why this regular expression isnt working?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm using this regex to validate a scientific notation in a textbox but it's not working. This is not allowing to type anything.

```
regex = new Regex("[-+]?(0?|[1-9][0-9]*)(\\.[0-9]*[1-9])?([eE][-+]?(0|[1-9][0-9]*))?");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using Darek Slager's .NET Regex tester to troubleshoot the expression? http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Comment: Might help if you posted examples of what should/ shouldn't pass.

Comment: + an example of how you are actually using the regex - are you testing to see if there are characters that do not match this, or that the entire string must match, or..??

Comment: Just ran a quick test, it matches this input: `-1`, `+2.1`, `3.0001` and `4e-1`. You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: The regex looks ugly but appears correct (if rather strict on the allowed input format, e.g. no leading or trailing zeroes in the mantissa, no leading zeroes in the exponent).

Comment: Maybe the regex itself isn't the problem. You say this is "not allowing to type anything". Does that means that keys you press don't have any effect? Maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your regular expression matches the empty string. An easy solution could be to add `^` in front and `$` at the end to require the entire input string to match the regular expression.

Here is a small test:

```
var numbers = new[] {
  "0", "1", "01", "+1", "-1", "+0", "-0", "1.9", "1.09", "1.90", "1e0", "1e01", "1e10"
};
var regex = new Regex("^[-+]?(0?|[1-9][0-9]*)(\\.[0-9]*[1-9])?([eE][-+]?(0|[1-9][0-9]*))?$");
var valid = numbers
  .Select(n => regex.Match(n))
  .Where(m => m.Success)
  .Select(m => m.Value);
```

Printing out the elements in `valid` will result in the following:

```
0
1
+1
-1
+0
-0
1.9
1.09
1e0
1e10
```

Notice how `01`, `1.90` and `1e01` doesn't match but I guess that is intentional.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this is what you're actually trying to do?

Here's a screenshot from [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/):

[image: Regex Explained]

Comment: As much as I like RegexBuddy, this is even harder to read than the regex itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another tester that I find very useful: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
If you're just looking to match a floating point number that includes scientific notation while capturing the exponent, then try this: [-+]?[0-9]*.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)? (From http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
[-+]?(0|[1-9])[0-9]*([.][0-9]*)?([eE][-+]?(0|[1-9])[0-9]*)?
```

is somewhat closer to what you want.... but maybe it would help if you gave an test set of expressions you expect to pass/fail